# How to use a .txt file as an command

Tags: file, batch-file

I am developing on a lot of batch programs that need to have a option, to do the work easy to the user. So he can type in the host, domain, IP address name in a text file, instead of editing 10 different batch files and 1/20 lines in one batch file.

I have an idea that might work if it gets a little push:

#### Command.txt

```
ping http:www.stackoverflow.com
ping1.bat
@echo off
Cd ..
Echo testing connection.
Type command.txt {please describe the solution here}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Format your code in a better way and/or try to explain better your problem/use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do "%%~a"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want a configuration file that you can reference from your batch files. I do this by setting environment variables that are defined in an .ini file.

Config.ini

```
host=myhostname
domain=mydomain
ip=10.10.10.1
```

Then in your batch files, use the command:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,*" %%A in (config.ini) do @set %%A=%%B
```

From that point forward, you will have 3 variables that you can use: %host%, %domain%, and %ip%.